# Karma / jasmine-marbles: test failure message not properly formatted

Tags: rxjs, jasmine, mocha.js, karma-jasmine, marble-diagram

I have added **jasmine-marbles** to my project and I am getting error messages like this:

```
Expected $[0].frame = 20 to equal 70.
Expected $[0].notification.kind = 'E' to equal 'N'.
Expected $[0].notification.value = undefined to equal LoadSuccess().
```

instead of something like this:

```
Expected 
    {"frame":50,"notification":{"kind":"N","value":{"payload":"[
...
to deep equal 
    {"frame":40,"notification":{"kind":"N","value":{"payload":"[
...
```

Test:

```
it('should loadData$', () => {
    const action = new LoadRequest('123');
    const completion = new LoadSuccess({});

    actions$.stream = hot('-a', { a: action });
    const response = cold('-a|', { a: {} });
    const expected = cold('---c', { c: completion });

    client.loadData = () => response;

    expect(effects.loadData$).toBeObservable(expected);
});
```

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.2.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.2",
   ...
```

How to fix the test failure message? Is it related to some karma reporter / plugin / missing library?

Comment: Can someone (with proper reputation :) ) create a new `marble-diagram` tag? The current `marble` seems to be related to something else. Thanks!

Comment: I've just added the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [package.json](https://github.com/synapse-wireless-labs/jasmine-marbles/blob/master/package.json),

```
"jasmine": "^2.5.3",
"jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
```

I don't know if it makes a difference.

Comment: I first tried to update both (jasmine, jasmine-core) to latest `2.8.0` - same result, but the versions provided in your answer made a difference. Thanks